# Help identifying Bike Frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a question about a bike a bought recently at a bike market in Berlin.

They marked it down as Rossin, due to the forks I am guessing. The frame is not Rossin from my internet searches, and there are no other stickers or branding on them, just some numbers which I will outline below and in pictures.

Picture two has marking "9857" and "4 Made in France"
Picture three has "61"
Picture five has marking "ō62"

Otherwise no other markings, but thought maybe some of you more experienced riders might be able to notice something about the frame that could help me identify it!

Kind regards,
CuriousBiker[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][9]][9]

Comment: Welcome to the site - loverly `80's road bike!   Looks like the 9th photo you added might have been lost, there's no link in the text.

Comment: Second, is the fork straight with the steerer?  It might just be the camera's angle, but the tines appear bend back toward the pedals just a little.

Comment: Thanks! Yes 9th photo would not upload, but there was no more identifying information. The fork is straight usually, you are correct that is just the camera angle :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this isn't really an answer but it's the best that can be done given the information provided.

"Made in France" is on the bottom bracket cable guide and not on the frame itself so it could be that just that part is made in France. Back in the day (generally speaking) bike makers tended to stick with parts that were local. French bikes had French parts etc. As time went on that began to shift to a global supply so it's impossible to say for sure.

None of the numbers help with identification.

The rear dropout might have something embossed on them that would provide a clue but there is no clear picture. If you saw "Shimano" stamped on the rear dropout we could guess that the frame was made in Japan. If you saw "Campagnolo" on the dropout we could guess that it is European or U.S. made.

The fact that the rear dropout is forged rather than stamped indicates that when new this was a medium to high quality frame. Narrowing down the quality assessment would require knowing the type of tubing used and how well the frame is assembled.

Comment: The dropouts look fairly distinctive. (I have no idea beyond that.)